# Dynamically embed youtube videos

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

I would like to embed youtube videos dynamically in a grid. Currently, the problem is however, that the displayed video thumbnails are not expanding to the size of the columns. 
So first, I define a wrapper for the responsive columns. Then I would like to create a container with according size and in the container I have the element videoId, which is supposed to stretch the video thumbnail to the size of the container:

```
</style>
    .wrapper{
    display:grid;
    grid-gap: 30px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(310px,auto);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(500px, 1fr) );
    margin-left: 30px;
} 
.wrapper > div{
    background: :#f0f0f5;
    padding: 0;
}
.video{
position: relative;
background: teal;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
}
.videoId{
    position: absolute;
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
{%  for video in videos %}
<div class="video">
     <div class="videoId">
    <div id="player_{{video.id}}"></div>
    </div>
    {# <p>{{ video.ytbtitle }}</p>
   <p>Channel: {{ video.channelTitle }}</p>#}
        <p>Score: {{ video.star }}</p>
     </div>
{%  endfor %}
</div>
```

And:

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var players = {};
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    {% for video in videos %}
        players['{{video.id}}'] = new YT.Player('player_{{video.id}}', {
            height: '300',
            width: '400',
            videoId: '{{video.id}}',
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    {% endfor %}
}
console.log(players);

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == 0) {  
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Can anybody help:)? The foundation of my code can be found on this website:
http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

Comment: Why do you tag php?

Comment: I have found it in a code snippet online and since I am a beginner I didn't know better...

Comment: This is not php question, So I have removed php tag